# How to auto replay with attachment using applescript in mac mail?

Tags: email, applescript

I am trying to set up an auto reply in Mac Mail that includes an attachment. I can get the auto reply to work with the text message but not with the attachment. I am trying to use applescript but I'm not really that familiar with it. I've tried

```
tell application "Mail"
    set {theSender, theAddress, theSubject} to {extract name from sender, extract address from sender, subject}
    set theBody to "Hi - attached you will find out paper, Effects of experimental forest management on a terrestrial, woodland salamander in Missouri, which you requested. If you believe you received this email without solicitation please let me know at dhocking@unh.edu.I hope you find our paper useful! -Dan"

    set theAttachment to "Macintosh HD:Users:Dan:Documents:Papers2:Hocking:2013:Articles:Hocking_2013_Forest_Ecology_and_Management.pdf" as alias
    set MyReply to make new outgoing message with properties {recipient:theSender, subject:"Hello: " & theSubject, content:theBody}
    make new attachment at MyReply with properties {file:_Attachment}
    --open MyReply --comment out if you dont need
    send MyReply --un comment this to auto send your mail
end tell
```

and I have also tried

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
    repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
        tell application "Mail"
            set theAttachment to "Macintosh HD:Users:Dan:Documents:Papers2:Hocking:2013:Articles:Hocking_2013_Forest_Ecology_and_Management.pdf"
            tell eachMessage
                set {theSender, theAddress, theSubject} to {extract name from sender, extract address from sender, subject}
            end tell
            set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Re: " & theSubject, visible:true}
            tell newMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:theSender, address:theAddress}
                tell content to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias} at after the last paragraph
            end tell
            activate
            send newMessage
        end tell
    end repeat
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I've never used an applescript before, so clearly I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Mail v6.2 on Mac OS 10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, after setting it as a rule:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        try
            set theAttachment to "Macintosh HD:Users:Dan:Documents:Papers2:Hocking:2013:Articles:Hocking_2013_Forest_Ecology_and_Management.pdf"
            repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
                tell application "Mail"
                    tell eachMessage
                        set {theSender, theAddress, theSubject} to {extract name from sender, extract address from sender, subject}
                    end tell
                    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Re: " & theSubject, visible:true}
                    tell newMessage
                        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:theSender, address:theAddress}
                        tell content to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment as alias} at after the last paragraph
                    end tell
                    activate
                    send newMessage
                end tell
            end repeat
        on error m number n
            display dialog "Error: " & m
            tell application "Mail"
                log "Exception in Mail action: (" & n & ") " & m
            end tell
        end try
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: Anyway, also your script works, so I haven't understood what your problem is. My script will display the error in a dialog. In case, post the error here.

Comment: When I add the script to my mail rules and then send myself the test email, it auto replies but without any attachment (in the case of all the scripts). I copied theAttachment directory path into my browser with / instead of : and it opened the file, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. I never get any error messages.

Comment: Is Dan the current user logged on?

Comment: Yes, Dan is the current user logged in. I've been looking through some other forums and it sounds like this might be an issue with Mail on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I also have ML and it works for me. Try attaching another file, a smaller one.